# Why do only the buttons that are not inside the form not work?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, handlebars.js

I'm building this single page web app for a school project, and it utilizes JQuery to load different handlebar templates.

For some reason, all buttons inside forms work and so the create account and login buttons all work but the other ones on the mainpage don't.

Before you answer, keep in mind I know that storing UUID in the Session's storage is not safe, but this is for a small school project and we aren't very concerned about the security of it all.

JS:

```
async function loadTemplate(templateName) {
    const response = await fetch(`templates/${templateName}.hbs`);
    const templateText = await response.text();
    return Handlebars.compile(templateText);
}
$(document).ready(async function() {


    let indexTemplateCompiled = await loadTemplate("index");
    let createAccountTemplateCompiled = await loadTemplate("createAccount");
    let mainPageTemplateCompiled = await loadTemplate("mainPage");
    let loginPageTemplateCompiled = await loadTemplate("login");
    let userGroupsTemplateCompiled = await loadTemplate("myGroups");

    $("#app").html(indexTemplateCompiled);

    $("#create-account-button").click(function () {

        $("#app").html(createAccountTemplateCompiled);
        const uc_form = document.getElementById("user-creation");
        uc_form.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();

            const data = new FormData(uc_form);
            const username = data.get('username_input');
            const password = data.get('password_input');

            try {
                const response = await fetch('/users/create', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({"username": username, "password": password})
                });

                if (response.status === 200) {
                    console.log("User created successfully");
                } else {
                    console.error("User creation failed", response.statusText);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Error fetching', error);
            }
            $("#app").html(mainPageTemplateCompiled);
        });
    });

    $("#login-button").click(function () {
        $("#app").html(loginPageTemplateCompiled);

        const uc_form = document.getElementById("user-login");
        uc_form.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();

            const data = new FormData(uc_form);
            const username = data.get('username_input');
            const password = data.get('password_input');

            try {
                const response = await fetch('/users/login', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({"username": username, "password": password})
                });

                if (response.status === 200) {
                    const json = await response.json();
                    const token = json.token;
                    await sessionStorage.setItem('currentUserUUID', token);
                    console.log("User logged in successfully " + sessionStorage.getItem('currentUserUUID'));
                    $("#app").html(mainPageTemplateCompiled);
                } else {
                    console.error("User login failed", response.statusText);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Error fetching', error);
            }

        });
    });
    $("#create-group").click(function () {
       console.log("test click")
    });

    $("#logout-button").click(function () {
        $("#app").html(userGroupsTemplateCompiled);
       sessionStorage.removeItem('currentUserUUID');
         console.log("User logged out successfully " + sessionStorage.getItem('currentUserUUID'));
    });

    $("#my-groups").click(async function () {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('/groups/list', {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': sessionStorage.getItem('currentUserUUID')
                }
            });

            if (response.status === 200) {
                const json = await response.json();
                const groups = json.groups;
                $("#app").html(userGroupsTemplateCompiled({groups: groups}));
            } else {
                console.error("Error:", response.statusText);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error fetching', error);
        }

    });
});
```

mainPage.hbs

```
<h1>SECA Web Application</h1>
<form id="search-events">
    <label for="search-input">Search for events:</label>
    <input name="search-input" id="search-input" placeholder="Enter your search term" required>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

<button id="create-group">Create a group</button>
<button id="my-groups">My groups</button>
<button id="logout-button">Logout</button>
```

I was expecting, for example when pressing the Logout button that it would do the actions inside of it and switch back to the indexPage template after removing the currentUUID from Session storage.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that you are binding your event handlers before the elements to which they are to be bound exist in the DOM. The way to fix this is by using [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). An example would be: `$(document).on('click', '#create-group', function () {})`

Comment: Thanks, it worked but then why does it work when on the index page, I click login and create account with my old method? it loads the templates accordingly and each template works for logging in and creating a new account

Comment: The index page works because you are adding the buttons to the DOM _before_ attaching click handlers to them. This line: `$("#app").html(indexTemplateCompiled);` executes before the event listeners are added.